# app.config multiple values by single key

Tags: c#, app-config

is it possible to have app.config file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="someKey" value="valueHere"/>
    <add key="anotherKey" value="valueHere"/>
    <add key="listOfValues">
        <value1/>
        ...
        <valueN/>
    </add>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I mean, I want to have a key in config file that returns a list of values.How to do it?
Think it's pretty easy, but I just can't find any examples

UPD : maybe I should put multiple values separated by semicolon and then just split them?.. But I think it is not very good idea...

Comment: You really should simply use xml serialization not the app.config to store a list of values.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I read linked topic, but it only shows how to add arbitrary number of values into single key and then split them after reading...It's not very good, in my opinion.

Comment: but there ain't no other possibility when you only consider the built-in keyValuePair

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think the standard key/value pair config settings can do it, but with a little more coding you can have all the configuration XML goodness you want with a [custom config section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx).

Comment: Great!That is really what I wanted, no splitting or another hacks, a  real solution ) Many thanks

Comment: Another simple option would be using SimpleConfigSections from Nuget :) Very less code and straight forward.

Answer (score 14):

Don't know if what you're asking is possible. But what I do is I concatenate values using a separator like ";" for instance.

So you have something like:

```
<add key="runningDays" value="Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri"/>
```

Then I split the value string from config using the separator to get the list of possible values for the given key.

Comment: I though about it, but what if some value will contain ";" ?.. When dealing with split i should really carefully select separator, I think it may be problematic in some situations...

Comment: You're right, the separator could be a problem in certain cases.